# Disable an entire dropdown element when a value is selected from another drop down options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, drop-down-menu

I have a JSP page with four drop downs, and one among them is a controlling drop down list with which I have to decide which other drop down that needs to get disable based on selection of any onchange event.

For example:

```
//Selecting dropdown
    <Select id="dropDown1" name=" selection">
    <options value="1">choice1</options>
    <options value="2">choice2</options>
    <options value="3">choice3</options>
    </select>

//Other drop downs:
     <Select id="dropDown2" name="filter1">
        <options value="1">put1</options>
        <options value="2">put2</options>
        <options value="3">put3</options>
     </select>

     <Select id="dropDown3" name="filter2">
        <options value="1">put1</options>
        <options value="2">put2</options>
        <options value="3">put3</options>
     </select>

     <Select id="dropDown4" name="filter3">
        <options value="1">put1</options>
        <options value="2">put2</options>
        <options value="3">put3</options>
     </select>
```

Further, when I choose `choice1` from drop down one, I need to disable `dropDown3` and when I am selecting `choice3` from drop down 1 then it should enable `dropDown3` and disable `dropDown2` and when choosing `choice1` it enables everything.

I followed some of the tutorials in JQuery which have function `removeAttr()` but since I am new to JQuery and Javascript, I am not sure how to put everything altogether and try to call `onchange()` event and do such? Can anyone please help to guide on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't quite understand exactly what you wanted, but the code to do this type of thing is pretty straightforward.

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mhr3T/)</kbd>

**jQuery:**

```
var myId;

$('select').change(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    myId = $this.attr('id');
    myVal = $this.val();
    if (myId == 'dropDown1') {
        $('select').prop('disabled',false);
        if (myVal == 1) {
            $('#dropDown4').prop('disabled', true);
        }else if (myVal == 2) {
            $('#dropDown3').prop('disabled', true);
        }else if (myVal == 3) {
            $('#dropDown2').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you gibberish. your solution did worked, I think I was using $('#id's) instead of the $('select') and so did got confused. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

You haven't really provided enough information for us to see what you want to disable based on what, however, in principle you can disable elements like this:

```
$("#dropDown1").on("change", function(){
  $("#dropDown2").attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

**EDIT**

As waldek_c says, you can get the value of the dropdown inside the callback using `$(this).val();` and disable stuff accordingly.

I would also store the element to be disabled as the option value or a data-attribute or something.

For example:

```
<Select id="dropDown1" name=" selection">
  <options value="dropDown2">choice1</options>
  <options value="dropDown3">choice2</options>
  <options value="dropDown4">choice3</options>
</select>

$("#dropDown1").on("change", function(){
  var dropDownToDisable = $(this).val();
  $(dropDownToDisable).attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

Comment: Thank you Jack for the response, I will try the same. also, I have mentioned below in my question based on what value get selected which `dropdown` needs to get `disabled`. Please let me know if you have got what I am trying to do.

Comment: `$(this).val()` inside `on` this can give You option value or `$(this).text()` to get option text

Answer (score 1):

First, you use 'options' instead of 'option' in your HTML. And then, 'prop' is the recommended way to set and remove properties:

```
$("#dropDown3").attr("disabled", true);
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dtAgX/74/) you are, a working fiddle. Hope it helps.